# How do you remove the start of something in this format "NAME:BomberOutfit"

Tags: node.js

I have a list of items I wish to remove the start of, but havent found any applicable solution to my problem.

```
AthenaItemWrap:wrap_452_cadet
AthenaItemWrap:wrap_481_realm
AthenaItemWrap:wrap_424_islandnomad
AthenaItemWrap:wrap_425_exosuit
AthenaItemWrap:wrap_457_binary
AthenaItemWrap:wrap_447_blizzardbomber
```

I wish to remove `AthenaItemWrap:` from every entry in NodeJS however, I've been told to use Splice or Slice but to my personal knowledge and experience with both of these methods, i've been unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```js
const str = 'AthenaItemWrap:wrap_452_cadet';
console.log(str.substring(15));
```

```js
const str = 'AthenaItemWrap:wrap_452_cadet';
console.log(str.substring(15));
```